# Facing Error - "Unexpected token var" in creating pie layout

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create some charts using this

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
var m = 10,
r = 100,
z = d3.scale.category20c();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.value(function(d) { return +d.qty; })
.sort(function(a, b) { return b.qty - a.qty;});
```

Comment: This `d3.scale.category20c()` and this `d3.layout.pie()` do not exist in D3 v5. Voting to close as *typo*.

Comment: Can you tell me in which versions these are avl ?

Comment: Those are D3 v3.x methods.

Comment: I think the error you specified is not related to D3 - likely it's due to an error in formatting as the execution environment doesn't expect a var declaration where it is declared. But with only a snippet it is impossible to know where. 
If it was related to the differences between D3 api versions, then the error message would be something like `Cannot read property 'category20c' of undefined`, when calling `d3.layout.category20c()`. Still, the API discrepancy also needs to be fixed as pointed out.

Comment: Exactly, I am getting same error with v3 too

Comment: how do i share the code please let me know